# How to get the parent item node on select of child in telerik kendo treeview

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, treeview

I want to get the parent item on select of child item in the treeview, and also want to find the selected node is parent node or child node.

Please let me know if anyone know how to achieve it.

Thanks in advance,

Chinnayya

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! it's generally helpful to add a bit of code showing what you have tried, and to give some context.

Answer (score 7):

In order to get the selected node you need to use [`select`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#events-select) event. According the documentation the select node is accessible using `e.node` where `e` is the argument to `select` event handler.

For getting the parent of this node, you should use [`parent`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#methods-parent).

For getting the data of a node, you should use [`dataItem`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#methods-dataItem).

So the total code would be:

```js
var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [
        { text: "Furniture", items: [
            { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
            { text: "Sofas" },
            { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
        ] },
        { text: "Decor", items: [
            { text: "Bed Linen" },
            { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
            { text: "Carpets" }
        ] }
    ]
});

var tree = $("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: inlineDefault,
    select : function (e) {
        console.log("node", tree.dataItem(e.node));
        console.log("parent", tree.dataItem(tree.parent(e.node)));
    }
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Check a JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/s5Qd6/